# Is it possible to make plugins for other smartphone apps not owned by yourself?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, plugins

I want to develop a plugin for Facebook for both iOS and Android. Do you guys know if this is possible? I've googled some around and could only find an answer for developing a plugin for your own apps.
Do you also know whether it is possible with PhoneGap?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: By plugin I mean some software to download which extends the official Facebook app. Kinda like a browser extension.

EDIT2: For one of my ideas for an app, I want to do two things: 1) block url-specific AJAX-requests from Facebook 2) Insert ads in the bottom

For another app, I would like to access the equivalent of Facebooks DOM to automate tasks, which would require a touch from the user.
I'm also asking whether a such app can be published in the iTunes Store or Google Play or whether I may only publish it for download from a third-party.

Comment: What you mean by plugin for facebook?

Comment: Agreed. Please edit your question and explain, completely and precisely, what "a plugin for Facebook" means.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, completely and precisely, what "extends the official Facebook app" means. This should take a few hundred words and should include two or more concrete examples of what the user experience would be.